# JavaScript loop through each TR and assign a data-label attribute with a value of a set of TH to each set of TD's

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a table that has 5 TH's then there is a variable amount of TR's that all contain 5 TD's. I want to assign a data-label to each set of TD's with the value of the set of TH's.

This is the result I want

```
<table class="table" id="basket">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th class="middlecolumnbasket">Frequency</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Item name">Product 1</td>
        <td data-label="Type">Download</td>
        <td data-label="Price">€4.99 </td>
        <td data-label="Frequency">Each month</td>
        <td data-label="Remove" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete244113" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Item name">Product 2</td>
        <td data-label="Type">Download</td>
        <td data-label="Price">€99.99 </td>
        <td data-label="Frequency">Each year</td>
        <td data-label="Remove" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete245466" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Item name">Product 3</td>
        <td data-label="Type">Download</td>
        <td data-label="Price">€99.99 </td>
        <td data-label="Frequency">Each year</td>
        <td data-label="Remove" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete253047" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Item name">Product 4</td>
        <td data-label="Type">Download</td>
        <td data-label="Price">€29.99 </td>
        <td data-label="Frequency">Each year</td>
        <td data-label="Remove" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete253053" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Item name">Product 5</td>
        <td data-label="Type">Download</td>
        <td data-label="Price">€49.99 </td>
        <td data-label="Frequency">Each year</td>
        <td data-label="Remove" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete253055" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I can only get the first set of TD's

This is my code

```js
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var a = 0; a < tr.length; a++) {
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var b = 0; b < td.length; b++) {
        var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
        for (var c = 0; c < th.length; c++) {
            var content = th[c].innerHTML;
            td[c].setAttribute("data-label", content);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="basket">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="middlecolumnbasket">Frequency</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€4.99 </td>
            <td>Each month</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete244113" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€99.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete245466" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 3</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€99.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253047" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 4</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€29.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253053" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 5</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€49.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253055" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I was hoping to do it in plain JavaScript.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First grab the text content of each `th`, put them into an array, and then you can loop through every `tr` and assign the `i`th child of the `tr` the `data-label` of the `i`th item in the array:

```js
const labels = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#basket th'),
  th => th.textContent
);
document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((tr) => {
  [...tr.children].forEach((td, i) => {
    td.setAttribute("data-label", labels[i]);
  });
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<table class="table" id="basket">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="middlecolumnbasket">Frequency</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€4.99 </td>
            <td>Each month</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete244113" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€99.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete245466" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 3</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€99.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253047" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 4</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€29.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253053" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 5</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td>€49.99 </td>
            <td>Each year</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete253055" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```